# Invariant violation with React testing using Mocha

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, jsdom

I'm trying to set up a React project using Electron and I've just started trying to configure Mocha as my test framework.

All is well if I run:

```
  "test": "mocha -w --require babel-core/register --require ignore-styles ./app/test/helpers/browser.js ./app/**/*.spec.js --colors --growl"
```

and my spec file just has a simple describe and assert that 1 equals 1.

The problem arises when I try and include a react component:

```
import style from './app.scss';
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className={style.title}> Hello World </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

When that is included in my test, even before I shallow mount it, I get:

> Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

I'm using jsdom and setting up my browser env like:

```
import { jsdom } from 'jsdom'

const exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    exposedProperties.push(property);
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

JSDom can take a html template and I hadn't supplied one so obviously React.render didn't know what element to render my app into.

When setting up JSDom you can supply a config object to `jsdom.env`, or in my case I just supplied a html template to `jsom()`:

```
global.document = jsdom("<!doctype html><html><body><div id='app'></div></body></html>");
```

As per the docs you can also set it up like:

```
jsdom.env(
  "https://iojs.org/dist/",
  ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
  function (err, window) {
    console.log("there have been", window.$("a").length - 4, "io.js releases!");
  }
);
```

where the template is pulled from a url, or:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env(
  '<p><a class="the-link" href="https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom">jsdom!</a></p>',
  ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
  function (err, window) {
    console.log("contents of a.the-link:", window.$("a.the-link").text());
  }
);
```

Using static HTML.

It also provides a less verbose method, the one I used:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
var doc = jsdom(markup, options);
var window = doc.defaultView;
```

Where markup is simply some HTML.